# search doesn't get result when the search term contains () after a word

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex

for example if there is a product with name '**playstation (white)**' ,if i search '**playstation**' or '**white**' or even '**(white)**' the result shows.but if i search '**playstation (white)**' the result is empty.

i think the bug is due to regex because when i tried to type for example: '**playstation (**'

this error occurs **Regular expression is invalid: missing )** .but i don't know how to resolve it.

when i tried to search '**playstation /(white/)**',

lets say there are 3 products : **playstation (white)**,**playstation (black)**,**xbox**

it shows **playstation (white)** and **playstation (black)**

here is my code

backend productController.js

```js
const getProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const pageSize = 10
  const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1

  const keyword = req.query.keyword
    ? {
        name: {
          $regex: req.query.keyword,
          $options: 'i',
        },
      }
    : {}

  const count = await Product.countDocuments({ ...keyword })
  const products = await Product.find({ ...keyword })
    .limit(pageSize)
    .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))

  res.json({ products, page, pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize) })
})
```

frontend searchBox.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const SearchBox = ({ history }) => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (keyword.trim()) {
      history.push(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push("/");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="q"
        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Search...."
        className="search-box"
        /* className="mr-sm-2 ml-sm-5" */
      ></Form.Control>
      {/*  <Button type="submit" variant="outline-success" className="p-2">
        <div style={{ color: "white" }}>Search</div>
      </Button> */}
    </Form>
  );
};

export default SearchBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use `$regex` you need to escape special symbols in a string that you get from a user.

But there is a better solution, I would advice you to use a text search feature of a MongoDD. You can read about it here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/ this fill enable you to use full-text search.

In short you will need to do the following:

1. Create an index for a field you want to be used in a search.
2. Change the query to use `$text` and `$search` operators.